# HTML loads, but scripts don't run

Tags: javascript, electron, parceljs

I've this script compiled through Parcel:

[`/src/Main.ts`](https://github.com/Klaider/EmptyElectronApp/blob/master/src/Main.ts)

```js
import { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } from 'electron';

alert('Hi');
document.title = 'Xxx';
console.log('Hello');
```

Entry HTML for Parcel:

[`/src/Main.html`](https://github.com/Klaider/EmptyElectronApp/blob/master/src/Main.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <title>Empty Electron App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>alert('Aaaaah!');
    </script>
    <script src="./Main.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm bundling with Parcel using:

[`/build.js`](https://github.com/Klaider/EmptyElectronApp/blob/master/build.js)

```js
// ...
const entry = './src/Main.html';
const options = {
    outDir: './build',
    publicUrl: './',
    sourceMaps: false,
    autoInstall: false,
    hmr: false,
    target: 'electron',
};

// ...
(async () => {
    // ...
    bundler.bundle();
})();
```

It seems like Electron is not running the scripts included in the entry point HTML (does not alert nor mutate the page title nor log to the console). Like I said, the `console.log()` does not produce anything to the host environment terminal running Electron. I've tested this further by inserting text nodes in the HTML, like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- ... -->
</head>
<body>
    Foo foo foo foo foo
</body>
</html>
```

The app renders `Foo foo foo foo foo` successfuly; the scripts don't do anything. Am I missing some configuration?

Here are more sources:

- [NPM config.](https://github.com/Klaider/EmptyElectronApp/blob/master/package.json)
- [Repository](https://github.com/Klaider/EmptyElectronApp)

Here's what the output HTML looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <title>Empty Electron App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>alert('Aaaaah!');</script>
    <script src="Main.d562fc5b.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

File structure (`/build`):

[image]

Comment: Browsers (including electron) can't load .ts natively, so unless your build script magically replaces the .ts file with a .js file link in the index.html file itself without _actually_ changing the data on disk: load the js file that gets built instead?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That is right, but Parcel does that: it replaces the TypeScript by a bundle JS based on the HTML, generating a new HTML.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've put the output I'm getting in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>In your `build.js` file replace the `target` option with `web` instead of `electron`.</s>

UPDATE: I actually found a better solution to your problem as you may need to use the right target at some time in your application. See below:

The issue is that `nodeIntegration` isn't enabled on your `BrowserWindow` although you specified it in the options. This is because `contextIsolation` is on by default and those two options cannot work together. Adding `contextIsolation: false` inside `webPreferences` when building your window should also fix your issue while keeping the parcel target to `electron`.